# Looping letter input

Tags: java, swing, loops, event-driven

I'm making a hangman game for school and I've run into a problem that I simply can't solve, maybe I'm overthinking, maybe I'm not. Anyways, I need to let the user input a letter, and if that letter is in the word used for the game (pikachu. I know, stupid choice but it's pretty basic and easy so I used that) then the letter is revealed, the problem is that after inputting a letter, the user can't guess any more letters. I need a way to loop through the letter input and revealing so that I can actually play the game.

I'm sorry if the solution is so simple but I just can't figure out what needs to change in my code in order to fix my problem because I'm very new to java.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PanDisp extends JPanel {

    JLabel lblOutput;
    JLabel lblGuess;
    JButton btnUpdateLabel;
    Image imgPkmn;
    FraImg fraImg;
    String sSecret;

    public PanDisp() {//Constructor
        KeyInput keyInput = new KeyInput();
        KeyInput.LabelChangeListener labelChange = keyInput.new LabelChangeListener();
        sSecret = "*******";
        lblGuess = new JLabel("Type will go here");
        lblOutput = new JLabel(sSecret);
        btnUpdateLabel = new JButton("Enter");
        add(lblOutput);
        add(btnUpdateLabel);
        addKeyListener(new KeyInput());
        setFocusable(true);
        btnUpdateLabel.addActionListener(labelChange);
        fraImg = new FraImg(imgPkmn);
    }

    public void GameOver() {

    }

    class KeyInput implements KeyListener {

        String sInput;
        String sWord = "pikachu";
        String sSecret = "*******";
        char chInput;

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            chInput = (char) e.getKeyChar();
            sInput = String.valueOf(chInput);
            lblOutput.setText(sInput);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        class LabelChangeListener implements ActionListener {

            char cWord;
            int nCorrect, nIncorrect, nNum;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if (sWord.contains(sInput)) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sWord.length(); i++) {
                        sSecret.replace(sSecret.charAt(i), sWord.charAt(i));
                    }
                    nCorrect += 1;
                }
                else {
                    nIncorrect += 1;
                    if (nIncorrect == 7) {
                        GameOver();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you think is going wrong? You have posted a lot of code here

Comment: @bhooks Basically I want everything in the "KeyInput" class to loop so the user can input multiple times but I can't figure out where I can put the loop. When I try I get multiple errors and can't figure out how to avoid them. Like I said I'm new to java so I don't want to ruin my code by doing something that I don't understand.

Comment: Your problem is that your mindset is off and has to be changed. Don't think "loop", and in fact get "loop" out of the equation. You're programming in an event-driven programming environment, and the loop you're thinking of belongs in the linear console programming environment. Instead think "state of object" and "behavioral changes to state changes", and you'll move much further in this quest. So change the state of your class -- number of guesses, number of correct guesses, and then change the response to the user's input based on this state.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for the advice, but how will the state of my help fix my problem?

Comment: Please see my answer below. No, I did not give you a direct answer for your specific code -- you have to figure out yourself what variables to use for the state of your GUI, and how to check the state in your ActionListeners, but I think that you can do this, and that you will be better off by doing that part yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your mindset is off and has to be changed. Don't think "loop", and in fact get "loop" out of the equation. You're programming in an event-driven programming environment, and the loop you're thinking of belongs in the linear console programming environment. Instead think "state of object" and "behavioral changes to state changes", and you'll move much further in this quest. So change the state of your class -- number of guesses, number of correct guesses, and then change the response to the user's input based on this state

For instance, if you wanted to create a console program that allowed a user to enter 5 Strings, and then displayed those Strings back to the user, it would be pretty straight forward, in that you'd create your String array, and then use a for loop to prompt the user 5 times to enter text, grabbing each entered String within the loop. Here "loops" like the one you're requesting work.

## Linear Console Program

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Enter5Numbers1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter 5 sentences:");
        String[] sentences = new String[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter sentence #%d: ", (i + 1));
            sentences[i] = scanner.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("You entered the following sentences:");
        for (String sentence : sentences) {
            System.out.println(sentence);
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

---

---

If on the other hand you wanted to create a GUI that did something similar, that prompted the user for 5 Strings and accepted those Strings into an array, you couldn't use the same type of for loop. Instead you would need to give your class an int String counter, perhaps called enteredSentenceCount, and in a JButton's ActionListener (or Action -- which is something very similar), you would accept an entered String (perhaps typed into a JTextField called entryField), only if the enteredSentenceCount is less than 5, less than the maximum number of Strings allowed. You would of course increment the enteredSentenceCount variable each time a String is entered. And this combination of increase a counter variable and checking its value will need to substutite for the concept of a "loop". So here the "state" of the class is held in the enteredSentenceCount, and the behavioral change we want is to alter what the button's Action does depending on the enteredSentenceCount's value -- if less than 5, accept a String, and if it is equal to or greater than 5, display the entered Strings.

## Event Driven GUI Program

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Enter5Numbers2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int MAX_SENTENCE_COUNT = 5;  // number of Strings to enter
    private static final String PROMPT_TEMPLATE = "Please enter sentence number %d:";
    private String[] sentences = new String[MAX_SENTENCE_COUNT]; // array to hold entered Strings
    private int enteredSentenceCount = 0;  // count of number of Strings entered
    private JTextField entryField = new JTextField(20);  // field to accept text input frm user.
    // JLabel to display prompts to user:
    private JLabel promptLabel = new JLabel(String.format(PROMPT_TEMPLATE, (enteredSentenceCount + 1)));

    public Enter5Numbers2() {
        // create GUI
        // First create Action / ActionListener for button
        EntryAction entryAction = new EntryAction("Enter");
        JButton entryButton = new JButton(entryAction); // pass it into the button
        entryField.setAction(entryAction);  // but give it also to JTextField so that the enter key will trigger it

        // JPanel to accept user data entry
        JPanel entryPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));
        entryPanel.add(entryField);
        entryPanel.add(entryButton);

        // allow main JPanel to display prompt
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Please Enter 5 Sentences"));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        add(promptLabel);
        add(entryPanel);
    }

    // Action class, similar to an ActionListener
    private class EntryAction extends AbstractAction {
        public EntryAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, (int) name.charAt(0));
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // check that we haven't entered more than the max number of sentences
            if (enteredSentenceCount < MAX_SENTENCE_COUNT) {
                // if OK, get the entered text
                String sentence = entryField.getText();
                // put it in our array
                sentences[enteredSentenceCount] = sentence;
                entryField.setText(""); // clear the text field
                entryField.requestFocusInWindow();  // set the cursor back into the textfield
                enteredSentenceCount++;  // increment our entered sentence count variable
                promptLabel.setText(String.format(PROMPT_TEMPLATE, (enteredSentenceCount + 1))); // change prompt
            }

            // if the number of sentences added equals the number we want, display it
            if (enteredSentenceCount == MAX_SENTENCE_COUNT) {
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(6, 30);
                for (String sentence : sentences) {
                    textArea.append(sentence + "\n");
                }
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Enter5Numbers2.this, scrollPane, "Five Sentences Entered",
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Enter 5 Numbers");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new Enter5Numbers2());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: (I'm wish you) happy new year :-)